# Run attribute validator only after __attrs_post_init__ ends

Tags: python, python-attrs

I have:

```
@attr.s
class Example:
    number = attr.ib(validator=attr.validators.instance_of(int), init=False)

    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        self.number = 'string'
        print('It seems, validation was running before:(')


t = Example()
```

How properly setup validation here? I want to validate self.number after instantiation.

Comment: What is `attr`?

Comment: Hello @warvariuc, this is a package https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There was a bit of a discussion when we implemented `__attrs_post_init__` whether to run validators before or after `__init__`.

We decided for *before*, because their main raison d'être is to protect the class from wrong instantiation and giving *you* the confidence about what's in your attributes.

---

That said, you can always run validators manually using [attr.validate()](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attr.validate):

```
@attr.s
class Example:
    number = attr.ib(validator=attr.validators.instance_of(int), init=False)

    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        self.number = 'string'
        # ...
        attr.validate(self)
```

We *do* [plan](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/pull/233#issuecomment-323351329) on making validation – and when it's performed – more flexible but nothing concrete came out of it yet.